# Why are my Nextflow processes not executing in parallel?

Tags: nextflow

I have written a Nextflow script with three process:

- The first process takes a pair of `fastq` files and aligns with reference genome. The process writes the resulting `SAM` file into `sam channel`.
- Second process takes input from the `sam channel` and creates a `BAM` file from it, and writes it into `bam channel`.
- Final process reads from `bam channel` and sorts the `BAM` files.

Following is the entire code:

```
#!~/bin nextflow

reads_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs('raw/*_{1,2}.fastq.gz', flat: true)
ref_genome = file('reference/genome/index/ref_genome')

process mapToRef {
    memory '20 GB'
    cpus 16
    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), file(read1), file(read2) from reads_ch
    
    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.sam") into sam_ch

    script:
    """
    ~/biotools/bwa/bwa mem -t 60 ${ref_genome} ${read1} ${read2} > ${sample_id}.sam
    """   
}

process samToBam {
    memory '20 GB'
    cpus 16
    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.sam") from sam_ch

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.bam") into bam_ch

    script:
    """
    ~/biotools/SAMTOOLS/samtools-1.12/samtools view -S -b ${sample_id}.sam > ${sample_id}.bam 
    """
}

process sortBam {
    memory '20 GB'
    cpus 16
    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.bam") from bam_ch

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.sorted.bam") into sorted_bam_ch

    script:
    """
    ~/biotools/SAMTOOLS/samtools-1.12/samtools sort ${sample_id}.bam -o ${sample_id}.sorted.bam
    """
}
```

All three processes successfully execute their commands. However, they are executed sequentially. For example, the first process `mapToRef` runs **sequentially** for all read pairs, followed by `samToBam`, which too, runs sequentially after all `mapToRef`s have finished execution. I was under impression that parallelization would "work" out of the box, but I must be doing something wrong. I am a complete beginner in Nextflow and would greatly appreciate any help regarding this.

**EDIT**

Output of `reads_ch.view()`:

```
[ERR2512393, /home/work/raw/ERR2512393_1.fastq.gz, /home/work/raw/ERR2512393_2.fastq.gz]
[ERR2512394, /home/work/raw/ERR2512394_1.fastq.gz, /home/work/raw/ERR2512394_2.fastq.gz]
[ERR2512391, /home/work/raw/ERR2512391_1.fastq.gz, /home/work/raw/ERR2512391_2.fastq.gz]
[ERR2512392, /home/work/raw/ERR2512392_1.fastq.gz, /home/work/raw/ERR2512392_2.fastq.gz]
[ERR2512390, /home/work/raw/ERR2512390_1.fastq.gz, /home/work/raw/ERR2512390_2.fastq.gz]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested it on my end with the following script:

```java
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

reads_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs('/root/test_nextflow/*_{1,2}.fastq.gz', flat: true)


process mapToRef {
  memory '1 GB'
  echo true
  cpus 1

  input:
  tuple val(sample_id), file(r1), file(r2) from reads_ch

  output:
  tuple val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.sam") into sam_ch

  script:
  """
  echo bwa mem ${r1} {r2}
  if [ ${sample_id} == "ERR2512393" ]; then sleep 10; fi
  touch ${sample_id}.sam
  """
}

process samToBam {
  memory '1 GB'
  cpus 1
  echo true

  input:
  tuple val(sample_id), file(sam) from sam_ch

  output:
  tuple val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.bam") into bam_ch

  script:
  """
  echo samtools view -S -b ${sample_id}.sam
  touch ${sample_id}.bam
  """
}

process sortBam {
  memory '1 GB'
  cpus 1
  input:
  tuple val(sample_id), file(bam) from bam_ch

  output:
  tuple val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.sorted.bam") into sorted_bam_ch

  script:
  """
  echo samtools sort ${sample_id}.bam
  touch ${sample_id}.sorted.bam
  """
}
```

It's producing the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the two processes are running in parallel (`2 of 2`)

It could be that yours are limited by the resources? If your PC doesn't have 40GB of memory and 32 CPUs, it will run them sequentially.

**EDIT**: By adding `sleep 10` to `mapToRef`, we can clearly see both of them are running in parallel now:

[image]

**EDIT 2**: Added condition to "sleep" on one of the samples:

[image]

**Final EDIT**: be mindful of the resources you allocate to your processes. You could use `${task.cpus}` and `${task.memory.toGiga()}` to facilitate the configuration of your processes so that they are not different from what you have defined and what is actually used. See [CPUs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#cpus)

Comment: Thanks @Law.
My execution screenshot also looks almost exactly the same.
Can you replace `touch ...` on your script with `sleep 5` to emulate long running tasks and confirm if the processes are running parallelly? I have well over 20GB memory and 16 CPUs on this machine, so limited resource should not be an issue.

Comment: @PPrasai, check again my edit, i was doing it ;)

Comment: When the first process shows `1 of 2`, does the second process start execution immediately? In my system, both reads from the first process need to be complete before the second process can start

Comment: Check my second edit. I have added a condition to `mapToRef` to "sleep" if one of the `sample_id` match one of the samples. As you can see, both of them runs in parallel first, since one of the samples doesn't match the condition, the other processes are executed afterward.

Comment: I seems to be working on your end...
Can you spot any issues with my code?

Comment: Try to lower the ressources specified. Also, in your `Input` channels, instead of specifying, for example, `tuple val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.sam") from sam_ch`, you should rather do `tuple val(sample_id), file(sam) from sam_ch` and in the script, do `~/biotools/SAMTOOLS/samtools-1.12/samtools view -S -b ${sam} > ${sample_id}.bam`

Comment: Also, I just noticed something... why is there 60 CPU defined in your `mapToRef` when you gave it 16 CPUs ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129268/discussion-between-law-and-pprasai).

Comment: Thanks @Law!
Reducing `cpus` to 4 on process and `mapToRef`, and `memory` to 4 GB make it all work parallelly! Thank you so much. Could you update your answer so that I can approve it

Comment: Well, I did say toward the end the following `It could be that your are limited by the ressources? If you PC doesn't have 40GB of memory and 32 CPUs, he will run them sequentially.` Also, you're welcome.